# Блоки как на pinterest

Tags: flexbox

Как верстаются такие блоки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="works-items">
      <div class="row d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap">
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/1.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/2.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/3.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/4.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/5.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/6.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/7.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/8.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/9.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
        <div class="col-4"><div class="works-items-block"><img src="img/works/10.png" alt="Работа"></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Выходит вот такая кракозябра.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы используете Bootstrap, но даже не посмотрели их документацию? :) Там это есть.

Comment: Я сделал как понял из документации, вроде как видно что указал в классах.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBdENG

Comment: Использую только сетку) Флексами не добиться такого?)

Comment: Даниил, привет! Нашлось решение?!

Comment: Вот нашел, отличное решение через css columns -> http://www.magisters.org/community/8/62